# Find number of spaces in a string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, space

How can I find out number of spaces in a string using JavaScript only?

```
"abc def rr tt" // should return 3
"34 45n v" // should return 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this works too.. Did not come to my mind before :P

```
str.length - str.replace(/\s+/g, '').length;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it also with a regex

```
"abc def rr tt".match(/\s/g).length;
```

```js
var x = "abc def rr tt".match(/\s/g).length;
alert(x);
x = "34 45n v".match(/\s/g).length;
alert(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.
It will split it on  and will subtract one to account for `0` element.

```
("abc def rr tt".split(" ").length - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Split on the spaces and get the length:

```
var length = "abc def rr tt".split(" ").length - 1;
```

Or write a nifty prototype function:

```
String.prototype.getWhitespaceCount = function() {
    return this.split(" ").length - 1
}

var x = "abc def rr tt";
var length = x.getWhitespaceCount();
```

Comment: @Zeta -- Yep..just realized that :\

Answer (score 1):

Pretty basic:

```
str.split(' ').length-1
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nvW33/)**

Answer (score 1):

regex should be faster than split, but previous answers has an issue...
when using match the return value can be undefined (no match/spaces) so use:

```js
("abc def rr tt".match(/\s/g) || []).length; // 3
("abcdefrrtt".match(/\s/g) || []).length; // 0
```